# Encountering Errors Running GitHub Project: Wavelet-pixel domain progressive fusion network for underwater image enhancement - Seeking Assistance

Tags: python, github

I encountered a error

```
PS C:\\Users\\91789\\Desktop\\Underwater-Image-Enhancement\\WPFNet\> python Underwater_test.py C:\\Users\\91789\\Desktop\\input C:\\Users\\91789\\Desktop\\New folder ./checkpoint/generator_600.pth

C:\\Users\\91789\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\\\Users\\\\91789\\\\Desktop\\\\Underwater-Image-Enhancement\\\\WPFNet\\\\Underwater_test.py': \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it and run it. [LiuShiBen/WPFNet.git](https://github.com/LiuShiBen/WPFNet.git) is the GitHub repo.

Comment: Don't add links to GitHub repos in lieu of adding the code to your question. Questions should be self-contained on this site alone, so please make a minimal reproducible example of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the link you provided; it seems the file name is 'Underwate_test.py' but the file you are running is 'Underwater_test.py' so it does not exist.